# Siunitx: Wrong parse in S-column tabular

Tags: siunitx

Multiple uses of a text file containing numbers include a representation in a table. I read the file line by line and save those in a macro for a later use in a table. I use the `S`-column specifier of `siunitx` to format those numbers. Unfortunately, the occasionally present exponents are not parsed, i.e. the mantissa is parsed, but the exponents still remain in the output with some space.

If I explicitely use `\num{\line}` instead, all is done perfectly (except, commas are not placed below each other). So, what's wrong here?

```
$pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

Minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
    locale = DE,
    round-precision=6,
    table-format=1.6e+1,
    round-mode=places,
 }

\makeatletter
\newread\infile
\def\preparetable#1{
    \@bsphack
    \bgroup
    \openin\infile=#1
    \let\\=\relax
    \newcount\linecnt
    \gdef\usetable{}
    \endlinechar=-1
    \@whilesw\unless\ifeof\infile\fi{%
        \advance\linecnt by \@ne
        \readline\infile to \line
        \if\relax\line\relax\else
            \xdef\usetable{\usetable \the\linecnt & \line  \\}
        \fi
    }
     \egroup
    \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS}
    Schritt & {Fehler} \\
    \preparetable{test.test}
    \usetable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and an example file:

```
    0.37159
    0.026349
    1.1273e-04
    1.8199e-09
    4.0825e-17
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `\read` and not `\readline`, which assigns the wrong category code to `e`. You also had many spurious spaces in the `\preparetable` macro definition.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
0.37159
0.026349
1.1273e-04
1.8199e-09
4.0825e-17
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    locale = DE,
    round-precision=6,
    table-format=1.6e+2,
    round-mode=places,
}

\makeatletter
\newread\infile
\def\preparetable#1{%
    \@bsphack
    \bgroup
    \openin\infile=#1\relax
    \let\\=\relax
    \newcount\linecnt
    \gdef\usetable{}%
    \endlinechar=-1
    \@whilesw\unless\ifeof\infile\fi{%
        \advance\linecnt by \@ne
        \read\infile to \line
        \if\relax\line\relax\else
            \xdef\usetable{\usetable \the\linecnt & \line  \\}%
        \fi
    }%
    \egroup
    \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS}
    Schritt & {Fehler} \\
    \preparetable{\jobname.dat}
    \usetable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The mandatory `expl3` version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
0.37159
0.026349
1.1273e-04
1.8199e-09
4.0825e-17
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    locale = DE,
    round-precision=6,
    table-format=1.6e+2,
    round-mode=places,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketable}{m}
 {
  \camelcase_table_make:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_camelcase_table_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l__camelcase_table_entry_tl
\int_new:N \l_camelcase_table_row_int
\ior_new:N \g_camelcase_table_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \camelcase_table_make:n
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_camelcase_table_row_int
  \ior_open:Nn \g_camelcase_table_stream { #1 }
  \tl_build_gbegin:N \g_camelcase_table_body_tl
  \ior_map_variable:NNn \g_camelcase_table_stream \l__camelcase_table_entry_tl
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_camelcase_table_row_int
    \tl_build_gput_right:Nx \g_camelcase_table_body_tl
     {
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l_camelcase_table_row_int }
      &
      \exp_not:V \l__camelcase_table_entry_tl
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  \tl_build_gend:N \g_camelcase_table_body_tl
  \tl_use:N \g_camelcase_table_body_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS}
    Schritt & {Fehler} \\
    \maketable{\jobname.dat}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```